# How to ask mean by groupby in sparse matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix (305316x65537), I want to ask mean by group by one column.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wn2L.png) The columns like this. How can I finish it?

```
import pandas as pd 
from scipy import sparse

genenum=pd.read_csv('/home/lzbhouruiyan/scRNA-kinetics-prediction/Ref/human_octamer/genename_id.csv',index_col=0)
genenum=genenum

genenumcsc=sparse.csr_matrix(genenum['index'])
genenumcsc=genenumcsc.T
allcsc=sparse.hstack([genenumcsc,cscX],format='csc')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3fmq.png)

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: I add them. I just want to finish the groupby function of pandas in sparse matrix

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the meaning of your question correctly
you can calculate the mean of numerical cols over the categorical columns,

```
import numpy as np

df.groupby(['categorical cols'])['numerical col'].mean()

#or multi cols 
df.groupby(['categorical' , 'categorical'])[['numerical','numerical']].agg([np.min , np.max , sum , np.mean])
```

Comment: Hi, I know this function can be finished in pandas. But if it can be finished in scipy sparse? Thank you!